# Find the subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $\{0\}$ and $\{0,1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Find the subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by: (a) $\{0,1\}$, and (b) $\{0\}$

Part a: The goal is to find the subfield, $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ that is generated by $X=\{0,1\}$. By Proposition 4.4, $K$ must contain $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $K$ is closed under arithmetical operations, it must contain all complex numbers of the form 
$$0\cdot p+ 1\cdot q=q, \text{ where } p,q \in \mathbb{Q}.$$ Let $M$ be the set of all such numbers. We claim that $M$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. Clearly, $M$ is closed under sums, differences, and products. Further $$q^{-1}=\frac{1}{q}$$ so that every non-zero element of $M$ has a multiplicative inverse in $M$. Hence $M$ is a subfield, and contains $X$. Since $K$ is the smallest subfield containing $X$, we have $K \subseteq M$. But $M\subseteq K$ by definition. Hence $K=M$, and we have found a description of the subfield generated by $X$.

Part b: The goal is to find the subfield, $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ that is generated by $X=\{0\}$. By Proposition 4.4, $K$ must contain $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $K$ is closed under arithmetical operations, it must contain all complex numbers of the form 
$$0\cdot p=0, \text{ where } p \in \mathbb{Q}.$$ Let $M$ be the set of all such numbers. We claim that $M$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. Clearly, $M$ is closed under sums, differences, and products. But there is no multiplicative inverse in $M$ because we would have $$0^{-1}=\frac{1}{0}$$ which is not an element of $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence there isn't a subfield generated by $X$.

My question is if this is correct? I feel like the second one might be but I am unsure.

Comment: What do you mean by the subfield generated by ${0,1}$? To me this would be all of $\mathbb{C}$ since you've included $1$ in your generating set. I'm not sure why $K$ contains all numbers of the form $0\cdot p +1\cdot q=q$ where $p,q\in \mathbb{Q}$. I would have though $p,q\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: i should have mention that proposition 4.4 states every subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes that's true but not relevant. You need to explain what you mean by "the subfield generated by ${0,1}$". Normally you are allowed to multiply anything in the generating set with any element of the entire ring (so you would be allowed to multiply $1$ by anything in $\mathbb{C}$ which would give you all of $\mathbb{C}$ again). Is this not what you mean?

Comment: That's the thing, I am getting confused because I would want to have some $i$ floating round as part of my element.

Comment: No, really, you need to define 'generated by'.  If 'generated by' means 'the smallest field containing' then the answer is $\mathbb{Q}$.  If 'generated' means as a $k$-algebra for some $k\subset \mathbb{C}$ then the answer is $k$, and if it means something else, then who knows.

Comment: No. It means that it is the smallest field containing them. So for part (b) there isn't a subgroup?

Answer (score 1):

You have done much too much work. Every field of characteristic zero contains a field isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. In particular, $\Bbb C$ contains $\Bbb Q$ itself. You may define the field generated by a subset $S$ of $\Bbb C$ to be the intersection of all subfields of $\Bbb C$ that contain $S$. Since $\Bbb Q$ contains $\{0\}$, it is the intersection of all subfields of $\Bbb C$ containing this set. Same for $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: So just to confirm the subfields generated by $\{0,1\}$ and $\{0\}$ are simply $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Absolutely not. The smallest subfield containing $\{0\}$ is $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Now I am completely confused. How is $\mathbb{C}(\{0,1\})=\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}(\{0\}=\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear: the smallest subfield of $\Bbb C$ containing $\{0,1\}$ is $\Bbb Q$, and the smallest subfield of $\Bbb C$ containing $\{0\}$ is $\Bbb Q$.